# nginx + tornado + supervisord

Tags: python, nginx, tornado, supervisord

I'm trying to bring this supervisord+nginx+tornado setup to work. Since the Tornado-files are reachable via IP:8000 and IP:80 shows me the 'Welcome to nginx' I thought that maybe my nginx.conf contains errors. I aim to let this deliver my tornado-site to the users at port 80.

nginx.conf looks like this:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    # Enumerate all the Tornado servers here
    upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;
        server 127.0.0.1:8002;
        server 127.0.0.1:8003;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    proxy_read_timeout 200;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml
               application/x-javascript application/xml
               application/atom+xml text/javascript;

    # Only retry if there was a communication error, not a timeout
    # on the Tornado server (to avoid propagating "queries of death"
    # to all frontends)
    proxy_next_upstream error;

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Allow file uploads
        client_max_body_size 50M;

        location static/ {
            root /srv/www/url/tornado/;
            if ($query_string) {
                expires max;
            }
        }
        location = /favicon.ico {
            rewrite (.*) /static/favicon.ico;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
            rewrite (.*) /static/robots.txt;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
    }
}
```

help is much appreciated.

This is the supervisord.conf:

```
[include]
files = *.supervisor

[supervisord]

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = unix://supervisord.sock

[unix_http_server]
file = supervisord.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:main]
process_name = main-%(process_num)s
command = python /srv/www/url/tornado/main.py
--port=%(process_num)s
--log_file_prefix=%(here)s/logs/%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s.log
numprocs = 4
numprocs_start = 8000
```

Comment: Try with `listen 80 default_server;` or putting a `server_name` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: add a server_name param to nginx config.

Also, what does supervisor say when you start your app?
If it's okay (`started`), take a look at tornado and nginx logs.

If you provide them here, figuring out the answer would be much easier.:)